# NTLM on IIS 8.5 on Server 2012, second web site failing

Tags: iis, server, ntlm

Maybe you'll be able to help me out.

My situation is this:

We are migrating to from Win2003 to Win2012.   We've got multiple web sites configured on the 2003 box and we can browse to each of the different names no problem at all, using Windows Integrated.

Well, we just fired up a Windows 2012 and started migrating to it but running into an ntlm 401 issue (log says specifically 401.2.5).

Changing the names to protect the innocent here:
Server Name:  Server

going to http://server/apps/asmx/servivce.asmx works fine.
We have a second IP assigned to a new the same box, on port 80, but configured so we can go to http://conapps/apps/asmx/service.asmx.   That should work, and return a simple wsdl, but it doesn't.

if we go to http://conapps/apps/anonymous/asmx/service.asmx, it works fine.

I've gone into the authentication tab, and have windows Integrated (and NTLM bubbled up to the top) but I keep getting the 401 errors.  Ironcially, if I set anonymous on, it works as expected.

As I said, if I take the default web site, and configure it to point to the same physical files on the disk, it works fine.   It's only when I try to go to the secondary name do I have problems.

So, anybody have any ideas what I *might* be missing?

Comment: Could it be the loopback check?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: Part of our end game is to be able to add/update service references inside of Studio.  Same scenario above occurs, if I use the physical server name, I'm fine, if I use the second name to the same physical box, I get 401s.

Comment: I thought about the loopback, I'll double check my registry again.   Maybe it's something in there I missed, or fat fingered, etc.

Comment: Hum, I wonder if NTLM relies upon a DNS entry...   We updated our hosts file to point to the next server, but not DNS.   We can resolve the web sites to the new server via host name, but it still didn't work.   As soon as we added to DNS, it seemed to fire up.

Possible?

After things were up and running, we were going to change the DNS entry from the 2003 box to the 2012 box.   That way we didn't have to do all of the path updates, etc.

Comment: Usually, when you get a 401.2, there will be an event in the event log. Have you checked? If so, what did it say?